# Онлайн воспроизведение видео из torrent файлов

Tags: c#, xamarin, torrent

Я знаю, что есть, такие плееры, как vlc, rox, которые могут онлайн воспроизводить видео из torrent файлов по мере их скачивания, но я не знаю, как реализовать это на xamarin C#. Я не знаю, можно ли это реализовать с помощью плагинов, или можно обойтись обычным плеером. (простите, я не мастер задавать вопросы... но может кто-нибудь может помочь мне...)

Comment: дело не в плеере а в 1. формате файла - не все форматы можно так воспроизводить и в 2. настройках конкретного торент клиента. Если ты закачиваешь файл последовательно (то есть отдаются в приоритет закачки в  начало файла и опускается приоритет кусков из конца файла) то вместе эти 2 пункта дают возможность тебе воспроизводить видео еще до того как файл выкачался

Comment: ну, торрент клиент не важен, ведь я могу "вручную" скачать файл по торренту, используя C#, дело лишь в том, каким образом воспроизводить файл по мере его закачки

Comment: еще раз: суть в формате файла и способе выкачки(приоретет выкачки на начало файла). А дальше ты воспроизводишь файл точно так же как любой полный. Ничего более роли не играет. Вот и качай "вручную" с приоритетом на начало файла.

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос для со, но в целом вполне реализуемый -- в некоторых коммерческих торрент-клиентах такое уже реализовано.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, задача вполне простая, правда я могу накосячить с тонкостями Xamarin (ибо не знаю его), но он очень похож на WPF, поэтому я буду делать на нем.

И так, вам нужно две вещи:

1. Торрент клиент. На C# один из самых популярных и функциональных, это [MonoTorrent](https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent).
2. Вам нужен плеер, который умеет либо работать со `Stream`, либо уметь буферно считывать файл. Вот тут я без понятия что у вас там на Xamarin, может есть готовое решение, а может, будете использовать как я, [VLC](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet).

Так, с этим разобрались, теперь код:

- Качаем с NuGet нужные пакеты (я для WPF возьму `MonoTorrent`, `Vlc.DotNet.Wpf` (контрол для WPF XAML), `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` (сам плеер).
- Создадим в проекте отдельный `UserControl`, будет некой оберткой над плеером.

  - В XAML пишем просто `<Vlc:VlcControl x:Name="media"/>`
  - В C# коде пишем нечто такое:

    ```
    public partial class VLCPlayer : UserControl
    {
        public VLCPlayer() => InitializeComponent();

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
            media.SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(vlcLibDirectory);
        }

        public Stream Stream
        {
            get => (Stream)GetValue(StreamProperty);
            set => SetValue(StreamProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StreamProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Stream", typeof(Stream), typeof(VLCPlayer),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFirstPropertyChanged)));

        private static void OnFirstPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var player = d as VLCPlayer;
            if (player is not null)
                player.Play();
        }

        private void Play()
        {
            media.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Play(Stream);
        }
    }
    ```

  Здесь мы инициализируем плеер (как сказано в документации), а также делаем `DependencyProperty`, которое будем пробрасывать нам `Stream` и в случае его изменения, запускать плеер.
- Далее следаем отдельный класс, который будем содержать в себе свойства для привязки, да и запустит весь процесс:

  ```
    public class MainViewModel : BindingBase
    {
        private Stream stream;
        public Stream Stream
        {
            get => stream;
            set => SetProperty(ref stream, value);
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
        }

        private double progress;
        public double Progress
        {
            get => progress;
            set => SetProperty(ref progress, value);
        }

        private TorrentState state;
        public TorrentState State
        {
            get => state;
            set => SetProperty(ref state, value);
        }
        public async Task StartDownload()
        {
            var engine = new ClientEngine();

            var torrent = await Torrent.LoadAsync("D:\\test.torrent");
            var manager = await engine.AddStreamingAsync(torrent, "Downloads");
            await manager.StartAsync();
            await manager.WaitForMetadataAsync();

            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Name = manager.Torrent.Name;
                while (engine.IsRunning)
                {
                    Progress = manager.Progress;
                    State = manager.State;
                }
            });

            var file = manager.Files[0];
            var stream = await manager.StreamProvider.CreateStreamAsync(file, CancellationToken.None);
            Stream = stream;

            await Task.WhenAll(task);
        }
    }
  ```

`BindingBase` - это реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтоб свойства наши обновлялись, вопрос не про правильность реализации, а вообще про сам принцип, поэтому я MVVM и прочее здесь опущу.

В `StartDownload` мы инициализируем клиент торрента, добавляем в него наш торрент файл (или что там у вас будет) как `Streaming`, это позволит ему качать куски поочередно. `await manager.WaitForMetadataAsync();` - ожидает получения метаданных торрента, без него получение `Stream` может выдать ошибку, ибо файла еще может не быть! Для наглядности я сделал `task`, который будет выводить нам информацию на экран (статус, название файла, прогресс), ну и самое тут главное, это `stream` - мы получаем `Stream` первого файла в торренте, который качаем и отдаем его нашему плееру.

- В XAML окна делаем самую простейшую разметку:

  ```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding State, StringFormat={}[{0}]}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Medium" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Grid>
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}%}" Margin="5 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <local:VLCPlayer Grid.Row="1" Stream="{Binding Stream}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
  ```
- А, ну и по клику кнопки нам надо лишь вызвать `StartDownload()`.
- Не забудьте еще задать `DataContext` (или что у вас там на Xamarin, название чуть может отличаться).

Запускаем, смотрим:

[image: Result]

Я из гифки многое вырезал (там просто черный экран и бегут проценты), но результат думаю можно увидеть. Заметьте, что воспроизведение началось только тогда, когда файл немного скачался (у меня это 6%). Я думаю, можно будет поиграться с настройками и изменить этот показатель.

И так, давайте поговорим о недочетах в моем примере:

1. Все в одной куче, не стоит так делать!
2. `Button_Click` - не используйте контролы из кода и наоборот, старайтесь максимально отвязывать их. За клики отвечает `ICommand`.
3. `CancellationToken.None` - сделайте токен отмены, а не глушите его как я, этот токен поместите во все async задачи. Так вы будете иметь контроль над процессом, сможете его остановить.
4. `Task.Run` - не уверен в этой конструкции... Скорей всего она нужна, но код, который внутри, лучше переделать на `IProgress`. Увы, `MonoTorrent` не дает нам событий, которые отдавали бы прогресс.
5. Как я говорил выше, воспроизведение начинается примерно на 6% (у меня это минута ожидания), это надо анализировать и исправлять, хотя я торрент просмотрами не занимаюсь, может такая длинная пауза и норма.
6. `Stream` следует закрыть после завершения его использования.

Собственно, вот вам и просмотр торрентов на языке C#, адаптировать думаю сможете под Xamarin, главное найдите плеер (в NuGet есть тот же VLC для Xamarin от разных авторов)!