# Воспроизведение видеофайлов по мере их скачивания, android

Tags: c#, xamarin, download

Я использую [Media Manager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) для
воспроизведения видео на android. Так я составляю запрос для скачивания видео:

```
var httpRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url11);
httpRequest1.UserAgent = "...";
httpRequest1.Accept = "...";
httpRequest1.Host = "...";
ttpRequest1.Referer = "...";
httpRequest1.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "...";
var httpResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest1.GetResponse();
```

Далее я пытаюсь получить Stream ответа и использовать его для моих целей:

```
//Вариант 1

CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(httpResponse1.GetResponseStream(), "videoName.mp4");


//Вариант 2

VideoView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => httpResponse1.GetResponseStream());
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play();


//Вариант 3

Stream str1 = httpResponse1.GetResponseStream();
FileStream str = File.Create(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", "vd1.mp4"));
str1.CopyToAsync(str);

CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(str, "vd1.mp4");
//ИЛИ
VideoView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => str);
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play();
//ИЛИ
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", "vd1.mp4")));
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(f);


//Вариант 4, также я пытался что-то сделать с этим методом, но из этого ничего не вышло

byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
      ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(ms, "name.mp4");
      //ИЛИ
      VideoView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
      CrossMediaManager.Current.Play();
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Также я пытался использовать это:

```
 FFImageLoading.StreamExtensions.AsSeekableStreamAsync(str).Result; //Result = Stream
```

Я также использовал разные плееры, такие как [VLC](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp) и [Octane](https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer). Все варианты не ребатают, даже с разными плеерами.

```
//Это писал MediaManager в одном из способов
setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
[MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI] getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.
```

VLC в одном из способов(нескольких) писал что-то вроде:

```
not enough data //(памяти на android достаточно)
your input cant be opened
cant open imem://:
что-то про mrl или mri
```

Octane же в одном из способов просто начал скачивать видео понлостью.
У приложения есть разрешения на интернет и внешнее хранилище/файловую систему(external storage).

Но, если полностью записать видео из стрима в файл, то его благополучно получается воспроизвести. **Также можно воспроизвесть его из оставшегося стрима(FileStream).**

Я думаю это как-то связано с Stream.Position. Даже, если я сделаю так со стримом(FileStream), куда копируется другой стрим, полученый из ответа сервера:

```
str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
str.Position = 0;
```

Position все равно не будет = 0.

Может нужно как-то копировать стрим по частям и передавать плеееру? Или больше работать с файлом? Что я делаю не так((?

P.s. в документации к [Media Manager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) не написано о возможности работы со Stream, но такой метод и описание к нему имеется

Comment: Не в тему, но `HttpWebRequest` уже давно состарился, умер и разложился, в посте какого года вы его откопали? Используйте `HttpClient` вместо старичка. Надеюсь, хоть Xamarin у вас свежий? А вообще, 100% метод - заюзать `WebView` для такой задачи, но это легкий путь, а вы, кажется таковой не ищете. :)

Comment: Спасибо, простоя использую генератор кода из curl, чтобы не писать headers вручную. Но я учту это Да... WebView можно использовать. Но проблема в том, что потом я собираюсь работать с торрент файлами, и воспроизводить видео во время скачивания, тут webView не поможет(( Хотя, я еще не пробовал делать это с торрентом, может то что я делал до этого не работает только с запросами(.

Comment: Здесь где-то я точно видел вопрос с ответом про торрент-файлы. А примеров с `HttpClient` здесь немеряно, даже среди моих ответов.

Comment: этот вопрос задавал я.

Comment: Этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1291963/373567? Тогда вы ничего не усвоили из ответа, перечитайте еще раз.

Comment: @aepot я все усвоил, просто мне было больше важно скачивани файлов через торрент, к тому же его код довольно сильно отличается, и я не мог использовать некоторые вещи

Comment: Не получилось зарегистрироваться?

Comment: куда зарегистрироваться?

Comment: Ваш аккаунт не зарегистрирован здесь. То есть как куки закончатся или будут стерты в браузере, вы потеряете к нему доступ. Придется еще раз создавать новый. Привяжите к аккаунту соцсеть или добавьте вход по логину и паролю.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Код выполняется слишком быстро, поэтому, видимо, какая-то системная информация не успевает скачаться.

```cs
Stream str6 = httpResponse1.GetResponseStream();
File.Create(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", "vd1.mp4")).Close();
FileStream st = new FileStream(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", "vd1.mp4"),FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite);
str6.CopyToAsync(st);

//ТУТ КАКОЕ-ТО ОЖИДАНИЕ(напрмер зависящее от Position потока)

var _mediaPlayer = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer(_libVLC)
{
  Media = new Media(_libVLC, new Uri(Path.Combine(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", "vd1.mp4"))))
};
VideoView.MediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
_mediaPlayer.Position = 0;
_mediaPlayer.Play();
```

MediaManager почему-то так из-под ножа не захотел работать, но зато заработал VLC

Comment: И да, ваша задача вот так вот в лоб не решается. Я бы сказал, решение, думаю, ближе к [этому варианту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144090/373567).